# filter not working in angularjs for JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, filter

I apologize if this has been answered beforehand I searched but couldn't understand the answers on other stack overflows so if they did have the answer I couldnt make sense of it. I am trying to filter the JSON data that is in the ng-repeat but it just brings up nothing whenever I type something into the input. Just a bit of help even if its just pointing me in the direction would be greatly appreciated. I have a jsbin that shows what I am talking about.

http://jsbin.com/ILEQEso/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **the filter can't reach nested properties**.

It can't filter `stories.title.$text`.

Possible solutions:

- Write your own filtering function.
- Somehow make the contents to be filtered available in a property which is not nested. For example: instead of `stories.title.$text`, make it available at `stories.title_text`.

Here is a working JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/esAteYI/2/edit

I have done two things:

1. Created a `stories.$text` property, including the contents of both `stories.title.$text` and `stories.teaser.$text` on it.
2. You can specify to which property tthe filtering should be applied. Look how I've changed the `ng-model` attribute of the search input field to `<input ng-model="searchquery.$text" />` 
   By specifying the `.$text` property, the filter will work only on it. So, it will not waste precious time trying to apply the search through the other properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your filter criteria like this:

```
ng-repeat="story in storytitle | filter:{'title.$text':searchquery}"
```

It will look for the search term on the title.$text property only.

Don't forget to set your searchquery to empty at the beginning in the controller:

```
$scope.searchquery = '';
```

Here is your updated Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/AQoJEMU/1/edit